# Google Chart Background Color

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm styling a google chart using the javascript api. I want to change the background of the area where the data is plotted. For some reason when I set background options like so:

```
chart.draw(data, { backgroundColor: { fill: "#F4F4F4" } })
```

It changes the the background of the whole chart and not the area where the data is plotted. Any ideas on how to only change the background of the plotted area?
Thanks

Answer (score 75):

pass the options like this

```
var options = {
    title: 'title',
    width: 310,
    height: 260,
    backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4',
    is3D: true
};
```

Answer (score 19):

add this to your options:

```
'chartArea': {
    'backgroundColor': {
        'fill': '#F4F4F4',
        'opacity': 100
     },
 }
```

Answer (score 12):

The proper answer is that it depends if it is classic Google Charts or Material Google Charts. If you use classic version of the Google Charts, multiple of the above suggestion work. However if you use newer Material type Google charts then you have to specify the options differently, or convert them (see `google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options)` below). On top of that in case of material charts if you specify an opacity for the whole chart, the opacity (only) won't apply for the chart area. So you need to explicitly specify color with the opacity for the chart area as well even for the same color combination.

In general: material version of Google Charts lack some of the features what the Classic has (slanted axis labels, trend lines, custom column coloring, Combo charts to name a few), and vica versa: the number formating and the dual (triple, quadruple, ...) axes are only supported with the Material version.

In case a feature is supported by both the Material chart sometimes requires different format for the options.

```
<body>
  <div id="classic_div"></div>
  <div id="material_div"></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
  google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart', 'bar'] });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,    400],
      ['2005',  1170,    460],
      ['2006',   660,   1120],
      ['2007',  1030,    540],
      ['2009',  1120,    580],
      ['2010',  1200,    500],
      ['2011',  1250,    490],
    ]);
    var options = {
      width: 1000,
      height: 600,
      chart: {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017'
      },
      // Accepts also 'rgb(255, 0, 0)' format but not rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2),
      // for that use fillOpacity versions
      // Colors only the chart area, simple version
      // chartArea: {
      //   backgroundColor: '#FF0000'
      // },
      // Colors only the chart area, with opacity
      chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: {
          fill: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.1
        },
      },
      // Colors the entire chart area, simple version
      // backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
      // Colors the entire chart area, with opacity
      backgroundColor: {
        fill: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.8
      },
    }

    var classicChart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('classic_div'));
    classicChart.draw(data, options);

    var materialChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('material_div'));
    materialChart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  }
```

Fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/csabatoth/v3h9ycd4/2/

Comment: just what I was looking for. To have the background color only in the chart area. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

It is easier using the options.

```
drawChart() {
    // Standard google charts functionality is available as GoogleCharts.api after load
    const data = GoogleCharts.api.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Chart thing', 'Chart amount'],
        ['Na Meta', 50],
        ['Abaixo da Meta', 22],
        ['Acima da Meta', 10],
        ['Refugos', 15]
    ]);

    let options = {
      backgroundColor: {
        gradient: {
          // Start color for gradient.
          color1: '#fbf6a7',
          // Finish color for gradient.
          color2: '#33b679',
          // Where on the boundary to start and
          // end the color1/color2 gradient,
          // relative to the upper left corner
          // of the boundary.
          x1: '0%', y1: '0%',
          x2: '100%', y2: '100%',
          // If true, the boundary for x1,
          // y1, x2, and y2 is the box. If
          // false, it's the entire chart.
          useObjectBoundingBoxUnits: true
        },
      },
    };

    const chart = new GoogleCharts.api.visualization.ColumnChart(this.$.chart1);
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I'm using polymer that's why i'm using this.$.cart1, but you can use selectedbyid, no problem.

Comment: this example show how to get a gradient. witch I was struggling to get right.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `backgroundcolor.stroke` and `backgroundcolor.strokewidth`?

See [Google Charts documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options).

Answer (score 1):

[image: If you want to do like this then it will help]

If you want to do like this then it will help. I use `stepped area` chart in the combo chart from the Google library...
where the values for each stepped area is the value for ticks.

Here is the link for [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/VikasRinvi/uwba6Ljy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you only need to put `backgroudColor: 'yourColor'` Ex:

```
var options = {
title: 'title',
width: 300,
height: 200,
backgroundColor: '#fff',};
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply add background option

```
  backgroundColor: {
        fill:'red'     
        },
```

here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/amitjain/q3tazo7t/

Answer (score -1):

**You can do it just with CSS:**

```
#salesChart svg > rect {  /*#salesChart is ID of your google chart*/
    fill: #F4F4F4;
}
```